# Converting HTTPS to TCP to HTTPS

Tags: http, networking, tcp, proxy, routes

Is it possible send a HTTPS (layer 7) request from a client, converting the package to TCP (layer 4) - as it needs to pass a TCP proxy in between, and then convert the TCP package to HTTPS (layer 7) again in order to make a call to the destination server in the internet?

1. I am trying to understand if this is a common pattern?
2. I would assume all the HTTPS (layer 7) will get lost during the conversion? Or is there a way to keep this information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question makes no sense for me. A layer 7 protocol like HTTPS makes use of layer 4 protocols like TCP, i.e. there is nothing to "convert" here. It's just how the data are looked at - as a byte stream on TCP, as TLS records on TLS or as HTTP messages on HTTP.  Notably HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 (and also HTTPS) use TCP as the underlying transport while HTTP/3 uses UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short answer NO.

The layers represent the information added to the packet to be sent from A to B, you can not remove parts of the packet and expect to reach its destination with the "message" (layer 7) in it.